# codeigniter use set() with insert_string()

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Using CI, I need to do an insert ignore with a subquery. I get a code igniter error when I try to do this:

```
$data = array(
            "user_id" => $user_id,
            "workload_id" => $wid
    );
    $this->db->set($data);
    $this->db->set("order", "(SELECT ifnull(max(`order`)+1, 0) FROM (SELECT * FROM default_workloads_users A ) B WHERE user_id=".$user_id.")", FALSE);
    //$this->db->insert("default_workloads_users");
    $ins = $this->db->insert_string("default_workloads_users");
    $ins = str_replace("INSERT", "INSERT IGNORE", $ins);
    $this->db->query($ins);
```

It tells me I am missing the second parameter to insert_string. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a way to hack around. Use insert_string first, then str_replace the subquery into the statement. New code:

```
$data = array(
            "user_id" => $user_id,
            "workload_id" => $wid,
            "order" => "@order"
    );
$ins = $this->db->insert_string("default_workloads_users", $data);
$ins = str_replace("INSERT", "INSERT IGNORE", $ins);
$ins = str_replace("@order","(SELECT ifnull(max(`order`)+1, 0) FROM (SELECT * FROM default_workloads_users A ) B WHERE user_id=".$user_id.")",$ins );
$this->db->query($ins);
```